# Python / Websockets : Opening file in socket callback reset the connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I'm making a website with a python server. I'm using the websockets library.
I would like to add log files to monitor my site activity during it is running.
But if I open a file in the socket callback, the socket connection is always reset on the opening.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def handler(websocket):
    while True:
        try:
            testFile = open("log", "w") # This line reset socket connection
            testFile.write('anything')
            testFile.close()
            message = await websocket.recv()
            await websocket.send('{"cmd" : "ERROR", "msg" : "This is a test"}')
        except websockets.ConnectionClosedOK:
            break

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "", 50000):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

EDIT : If I remove the try except block, I got the following error :

```
connection handler failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\server.py", line 231, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self)
  File "server2.py", line 52, in handler
    message = await websocket.recv()
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 552, in recv
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\protocol.py", line 929, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: received 1001 (going away); then sent 1001 (going away)
```

(I have also tried with another socket library (simple_websocket_server) and the issue was the same)

Is there a way to avoid this behavior ? If not, Is there another way to get logs during server execution ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. But in my tests, the current working directory is writable by the process and the `log` file is successfully created. Can you use a full path to a writable file and test again?

Comment: What do you mean by "full path to a writable" ? Absolute path ?
In my case file is correctly written too. But my socket connection is reseted (The browser page is refreshed).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this might help but you could create a logger using the logging library: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Comment: This is a good workaround to my issue even if it doesn't explain the problem. Thank you ;)

Comment: I still have an issue : Accessing the log file during execution, reset the socket.

Comment: try only accessing the file in read only mode by writing another program that contains.      f = open("logfile", 'r')                                                                                                                       print(f.readlines())

Comment: also create the log file before async def handler(websocket)  with 'w+' , then append to it with 'a+' within the async def handler(websocket) function.

Comment: I have tried, it's not better. On the second logging.info call I got the same behavior than with the classic file opening

Answer (score 0):

I understood my issue. The weird behavior comes from Windows WSL. I tested the same code on a real Linux and there is no problem. For now, I haven't any solution on Windows WSL.